# get actual path of multiple images from URI

Tags: java, android, uri, android-gallery

i am very new to android and coding and i am stuck here.i have a gridview that is showing images from my SDCard. but my gridview not showing anything. 
My Uri looks like as below:

```
[content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A252,content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A68,content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A67,content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A172]
```

i have tried many ways to convert this uri to actual path but nothing work for me

i tried this code but it leads to crash my app:

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI (Uri contentUri) {
    String path = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return path;
}
```

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARaq.png)

this is how i open gallery:

```
 btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            }
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

This onActivityResult() Method code:

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        // Get the Image from data
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        imagesEncodedList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (data.getData() != null) {

            Uri mImageUri = data.getData();
            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();

            mArrayUri.add(mImageUri);
            uriImage = mArrayUri.toString();// this string i store in sqlite
            galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mArrayUri);
            gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
            gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);


        } else {
            if (data.getClipData() != null) {
                ClipData mClipData = data.getClipData();
                ArrayList<Uri> mArrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mClipData.getItemCount(); i++) {

                    ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                    Uri uri = item.getUri();
                    mArrayUri.add(uri);
                    uriImage = mArrayUri.toString();//this string store in sqlite
                    // Get the cursor
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    // Move to first row
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imageEncoded = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    imagesEncodedList.add(imageEncoded);
                    cursor.close();
                    galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), mArrayUri);
                    gvGallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
                    gvGallery.setVerticalSpacing(gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing());
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) gvGallery
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    mlp.setMargins(0, gvGallery.getHorizontalSpacing(), 0, 0);

                }
                Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images" + mArrayUri.size());
            }
        }

    } else if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

this is how i get string from sqlite in Adapterclass:

```
final  String image_string = product.getFimage();//get string from sqlite
```

and send to share prefrence:

```
SharedPreferences settings = mCtx.getSharedPreferences("image_My_str", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("img_str", image_string);
            editor.commit();
```

In my display activity i get this string from Shared preference:

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("image_My_str", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String encodedImage = settings.getString("img_str", "");
```

and here i convert that string to URi:

```
    Uri mImageUri = Uri.parse(encodedImage);

       Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Images URI  " + mImageUri);

            try {
                inputStream = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mImageUri);
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Images File  " + inputStream);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Images bitmap  " + bitmap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (bitmap != null) {
                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(EditMapsActivity.this, "image not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

My URI looks like:

```
[content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A252,content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A68,content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A67,content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A172]
```

Comment: `have tried many ways to convert this uri to actual path`. You should not try to do so to begin with. Just use these uri directly. For instance to open an input stream.

Comment: but how ? i don't understand.

Comment: InputStream is = getContentRecolver().openInputStream(uri).

Comment: it gives null. please check screenshot.

Comment: check my updated post. i post relevant code

Comment: Your used 'uri' contains a lot of content schemes. That will not work. Use only one. Please adapt your post.

Comment: `imageFile = getApplicati.....` Please write readable code. You open an input stream so call it a stream. Not a file.

Comment: i use  `InputStream imageFile;` not file

Comment: and i store multiple images so my uri contains more than one content

Comment: `i use InputStream imageFile; ` Yes. That makes for unreadable code. Better: `InputStream imageStream;`  That is what i said. Yet much better: `InputStream inputStream;`.

Comment: `so my uri contains more than one content`. No. That string contains multiple content schemes. Handle them separately as an uri equals one content scheme.

Comment: how can i handle that Uri ?

Comment: As you do now..

Comment: but using this code i am not getting images

Comment: Then what do you get?

Comment: getting null value

Comment: For what? If you want help you should come to the point and not let us guess. Show complete code with one content scheme.

Comment: sorray if i am confusing you. i am newbie to programming

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214881/discussion-between-nullpointer-and-blackapps).